# Can I force report onto a single, long, scroll-able page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to force an 8 page report onto a single page.

So the current situation is this:
[image]

Tomorrow the report might be only 6 pages long - or maybe 9 pages but I'd like to force the report to always render on 1 page.

It will obviously be a long page but the user would then just scroll down the page.

Is this possible?
Can I implement this out-of-the-box or is it more involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - set the report `InteractiveSize` -> `Height` property to **0cm**.

You can still set the `PageSize` properties to the page size required when printing.

Comment: +1 thanks (although a minute behind `Nogard`!) - where do I find this property?

Comment: I think I actually got him by a few seconds on the answer, but thought I'd do an edit and add the PageSize info, which maybe reset things. That said, I'm clearly slow on answering your second question, so +1 for him on that front and I'll suggest you accept his as the accepted answer.

Comment: ....it's tough at the top Ian! On the plus side RS is a good app to be answering questions on as this site is more focused on `C#`, `Java` ... so usually you get more time to answer RS questions; there just aren't as many of them.

Comment: just added this related question [HERE ON SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065843/can-i-force-a-chart-at-the-top-of-a-report-to-always-be-visible)

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

In Report properties set `InteractiveSize` -> `Height` to 0 (this forces to display on one page)

It can be found here:
1) Go to View tab -> Check-in Properties
2) Search for `InteractiveSize` in appeared window
[image]

Comment: +1 ok - where do I find this property? If I right-click the border around the report in Design mode I can see `Report properties...` but there's no `InteractiveSize` option?

Comment: thanks - found it - although I use the Designer rather than the Builder. Is it possible to then hide the control that is used to move through the pages of the report? (as it is now redundant)

Comment: this control is called "toolbar" and contains not only Pagination, but also Search and Export controls. Programatically it can be hidden, but solely from report - I doubt so.