# Can I force a Chart at the top of a report to always be visible

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following report:

[image]

In `Excel` I'd use something called `Freeze Pane` below the chart ....this would mean as the user scrolls down, the table will scroll, but the chart would always remain visible.

Is it possible to implement this behavior in `RS`?

**EDIT**

**Note: the chart and the tablix use different `Datasets`**

Comment: I'm really impressed with your graph!  How'd you do those groupings with the x-axis labels?

Comment: @hurleystylee sounds like you need to add a new question to `SO`.

Comment: Good call, @whytheq:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025206/how-to-span-months-and-years-in-ssrs-graph-axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get this going with a bit of tweaking.

With **Tablix** objects, you have the option to fix header rows, i.e. they will stay at the top of the page when scrolling.

You can set this at the **Tablix** level:

[image]

Or at the row level with **Advanced Mode** set by using the `FixedData` property:

[image]
[image]

So what you can do to take advantage of this is to insert a **Chart** into those repeating Header rows. I tested this with a basic report:

[image]

This did succeed in having the **Chart** scroll with the **Tablix**, so will fulfil your requirements. One warning - it didn't look good when I did this (overlapping cells and the like), but it was a report with zero formatting so hopefully this will be helpful for you, anyway.

**Edit after comment:**

In my simple report example I added a new Dataset to the report, and pointed the embedded Chart to this new Dataset - this didn't work, as every time I did this it would always revert to the old Dataset (i.e. the one specified at the **Tablix** level).

However, what you can do instead is use a **Subreport**, which contains the required **Chart**, and embed this **Subreport** in the **Tablix** header. I just tried it now and it worked as required; the **Chart** using the second Dataset was fine and it scrolled with the **Tablix** as required.

So it's still a viable option with multiple Datasets, you just need the extra step of using a **Subreport**:

**New report:**

[image]

**Subreport:**

[image]

Comment: +1 hmmm - apologies but I've amended the OP with some important info

Comment: ...in your first screenprint is it not one of  the column header boxes that you need to tick?

Comment: Yes, you can try that, but if it doesn't work then you need to look at doing at the row level through the Advanced Properties. I think user @Nathan has an excellent explanation for why this first option might not work at one of your other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121989/keep-report-header-visible-while-scrolling.

Comment: ...I can get this to work in the report preview mode - but it doesn't seem to want to deploy - I wonder if there are some further settings that I am missing. I've even tested on a very very simple report set up just to test this feature and again its working in the preview but not in the report that is deployed to IE ! Should I start another question concerning deployment?

Comment: A new question might be your best option. Not much help for you, but in the above example I too only ran it in preview mode before posting, but I tested just now and can confirm that it also worked in Report Manager. Versions were IE 10 and 2008R2 SP1.