# How to span months and years in SSRS graph axis?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I really like the spanning of Months and Years in the x-axis in the following SSRS graph:

[image: SSRS graph with date groupings spanned in x-axis]

How do I do that!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the dates into several columns in the Dataset:

[image]

Add those columns as Category Groups of your bar chart:

[image]